# Sequence limit to infinity $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1{n^4}\left(\frac1{a_1}+\frac2{a_2}+\frac3{a_3}+\cdots+\frac n{a_n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Can you help me with this question?

> Let $a_n$ a sequence of real numbers such that $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n}{1+na_n}$. Evaluate this limit: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac1{n^4}\left(\dfrac1{a_1}+\dfrac2{a_2}+\dfrac3{a_3}+\cdots+\dfrac n{a_n}\right)$$

I tried with Stolz:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1/n^4)*(1/a_1+2/a_2+3/a_3+...+n/a_n)$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+1)/(a_{n+1}((n+1)^4-n^4)))=$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+1)/(a_{n+1}(4n^3+6n^2 + 4n +1))$

but I don't know what to do here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is okay now?

Answer (score 4):

Let $b_n=1/a_n$. Then $b_1=1$ and 
$$ b_{n+1} = \frac{1+n a_n}{a_n} = n + b_n, $$
such that $b_n=1+\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n^2-n+2}{2}$ holds by induction. By invoking Cesàro-Stolz we have

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k b_k}{n^4} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(n+1) b_{n+1}}{(n+1)^4-n^4}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{8}}. $$

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence formula can be written as:

$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n}+n$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{a_1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n^2-n+2}{2}$$

That means the sum in the parantheses is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{a_k} &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k^2-k+2)}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^3-\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+2\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{2n(n+1)}{2}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

And thus, the limit is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{2n(n+1)}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{8}$$